# eclipse keyboard

Tags: eclipse, keyboard

i have encountered a really weirdest bug in eclipse, i would love if someone will help with it.

after a while of coding eclipse simply starts to "mix up" with the letters that are being typed. meaning i press 's' and it displays a different letter 'o' and it happens for other keys as well d becomes an e...and so on.

the weird thing is that out side of eclipse every the keyboard works fine... 
and if i restart eclipse every think goes back to normal...till it happens again

i have switched keyboard, reinstalled eclipse... any other ideas?

i work with windows XP, and galileo-php-eclpse

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you use combination of keys <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>SomeOtherLetter</kbd>. If you don't choose SomeOtherLetter quick enough keyboard will be switched to some other defined in `Control Panel -> Regional And Language Options -> Languages -> Details...`

After restarting Eclipse will pickup default keyboard language.

Comment: OMG you are so right... how embarrassing ... :)
any way thanks.

me

Comment: no it's not embarrasing at all. how do you think i got the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just do a Alt+Shift it will switch among the languages of your windows.
For example in my system I have defined two languages German and English So if I do Alt+shift 
It switches to German from English and vise versa.